# Counting unique value combinations for all columns in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the count of unique values for all columns in my dataframe.

I have more than 400 columns in my dataframe and I have tried the following:

```
code:dfi.groupby([column names]).size().to_frame('count').reset_index()
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Length of passed values is 4462, index implies 0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: does `df.nunique()` give you want you want, or are you looking for unique combinations of all columns for each row?

Comment: So you have a dataframe with 400 columns, let's call the columns c1, c2, .., c400. Also assume c1 have values A, B and C and some other  values for other columns. Their counts are 100, 200, 400. So you want output c1 : A : 100, B : 200, C : 400, c2 ..., c3 ...., c400 ....., like that.? OR c1 : 3, c2 : ..., c3: ..., C400 : .....

Comment: I want the result to be: if c1=A,c2=B,c3=c then count 1. c1=A,c2=B,c3=D then count 1, the count will increase by 1 if the same combination gets repeated.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Creating a random dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': ['A','B','A','A','B','A','A','A','B'], 'x2': [1,3,2,2,3,1,2,3,3], 'x3': [1,0,2,2,3,1,2,3,0], 'x4':[1,0,2,1,3,1,2,3,0]})
print(df)
  x1  x2  x3  x4
0  A   1   1   1
1  B   3   0   0
2  A   2   2   2
3  A   2   2   1
4  B   3   3   3
5  A   1   1   1
6  A   2   2   2
7  A   3   3   3
8  B   3   0   0
```

**Step 2:** Counting unique rows

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(list(df.columns))[list(df.columns)[0]].transform('count')
df=df.drop_duplicates().reset_index().drop(['index'],axis=1)
print(df)
  x1  x2  x3  x4  count
0  A   1   1   1      2
1  B   3   0   0      2
2  A   2   2   2      2
3  A   2   2   1      1
4  B   3   3   3      1
5  A   3   3   3      1
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What I am trying to do is a bit complicated, I am trying to find the count of row values combination for all columns.

Comment: So, if there are 10 rows, with each being the duplicate, then you want 5? right?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. but the count will be 2, because each of the five rows has been repeated twice.

Comment: Check it now. Is that what you want?